# AJAX: Invalid JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Im using ajax to read my json data using

> http:xxx.myserver.com/myfolder/example.json

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http:xxx.myserver.com/myfolder/example.json",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data, status) {
        alert("success"+data+":::"+status);
    },
    error:function(request, status, error) {
        alert("Error:"+JSON.stringify(request)+":::"+status+"::"+error);
    },
});
```

For this i get output like below

> Error:{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}:::error::

I googled for the solution some says to replace json to jsonp if i replace

> dataType:json to dataType:jsonp

I got output like

> Error{"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}:::parsererror::Error: jQuery110107852220840286463_1387290139272 was not called

It is not at all entering **success** function.

Please anyone provide me solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the browser developer console to directly examine the server response.

Comment: Please use a descriptive question title.

Comment: You can only use JSONP if the web service supports it, and you only need it if your script is hosted on another domain than the ajax url. (if they differ, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: How are you calling it? link/button click?

Comment: Using `jsonp` would have made through CORS, however you have to define the `header` in server.

Comment: Im calling it in document.ready function itself

Comment: In browser(chrome24.0.1312.70) console im getting **error** like `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxx.myserver.com/myfolder/example.json. Origin http://myserver:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution for my problem.

Your json should be in this format **Eg:**`jsonCallback({"sites":[{"siteName": "JQUERY4U","domainName": "http://www.jquery4u.com"},{"siteName": "BLOGOOLA","domainName": "http://www.blogoola.com"},{"siteName": "PHPSCRIPTS4U","domainName": "http://www.phpscripts4u.com"}]});`

I changed my response to **jsonCallBack**

```
    $.ajax({
    url:"http:xxx.myserver.com/myfolder/example.json?callback=?",
    dataType:"jsonp",
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType:"application/json",
    success:function(data, status) {
        alert("success"+JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error:function(request, status, error) {
        alert("Error:"+JSON.stringify(request)+":::"+status+"::"+error);
    },
});
```

I get into success function and get my json response. Thanks for your help. This is because of cross domain problem.